# Is it possible to place a 3D object in a 3D terrain in Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Using this tutorial (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-terrain/) I have given my map a 3D terrain. However, when I add try to add a 3D object (GLTF format) as in this example (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/) then the 3D object does not appear at all.

Either the object is inserted but is covered by the 3D terrain or it is not inserted at all. If it is the former, then my question would be if it is possible to adjust the height of a 3D object in a 3D terrain.

With a 2D terrain in the map and **the same implementation of the 3D object**, the object is visible.

Would be really grateful for any help and I'll try to answer any questions that may arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is, manually you only have to modify the variable `const modelAltitude = 0;` which is by default at sea level. But if what you want is to calculate automatically it's a bit harder, you have to query the terrain layer as [it's shown here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/query-terrain-elevation/) and then use the result to set the `modelAltitude` variable, so you have to defer its creation and consecuently the rest of the 3D layer. Other option is to manipulate the transformation matrix array once the object is already positioned, but that's a bit of a nightmare.

As an alternative option, I was able to make it using a [Mapbox plugin](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox/) that I'm maintaining on GitHub, and helps to deal with the complexity of 3D objects on Mapbox.
You have an [example on how to do it](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox/blob/master/examples/21-terrain.html) using the model of a glacier mixed with the Alps terrain layer
[image]

Indeed, as terrain layer is automatically detected, the object will be positioned at the altitude defined by its 3rd coordinate.

```js
window.tb = new Threebox(
            map,
            map.getCanvas().getContext('webgl'),
            {
                realSunlight: true,
                sky: true,
                terrain: true,
                enableSelectingObjects: true, 
                enableTooltips: true,
            }
        );

... 

        map.on('style.load', function () {

            // stats
            stats = new Stats();
            map.getContainer().appendChild(stats.dom);
            animate();

            map.addLayer({
                id: mapConfig.names.customLayer,
                type: 'custom',
                renderingMode: '3d',
                onAdd: function (map, mbxContext) {

                    var options = {
                        obj: mapConfig.PAR.obj,
                        type: 'gltf',
                        scale: 1,
                        units: 'meters',
                        rotation: mapConfig.PAR.rotation,
                        anchor: 'auto'
                    }

                    tb.loadObj(options, function (model) {
                        model.setCoords(mapConfig.PAR.origin);
                        tb.add(model);
                    })

                },

                render: function (gl, matrix) {
                    tb.update();
                }
            });

        });
```